# Homeomorphism $f : (–1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Working through "Topology Without Tears", and Sidney Morris defines homeomorphism on p 91:

> Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T_1)$ be topological spaces. Then they are said to be homeomorphic if there exists a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ which has the following properties:
>   (i) $f$ is one-to-one (that is $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ implies $x_1=x_2$)
>   (ii) $f$ is onto (that is, for any $y\in Y$ there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$)
>   (iii) for each $U \in T_1, f^{-1} (U) \in T$, and
>   (iv) for each $V \in T, f(V) \in T_1$

For an example, there are functions that are homeomorphic from $(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, like $f(x)=e^x – e^{–x}$ and $f(x)=ln(1+x) – ln(1–x)$. Alternatively, the map $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$ does not allow for a homeomophism as it is not onto (ii from the definition).

Graphically, the map that doesn't allow for the homemorphism looks like a parabola (even) in that domain while the map that does allow for the homeomorphism looks odd.

Are my functions (and logic) respectively correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your first function, $f(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$ is not a homeomorphism $(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ but rather $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Good point. Are the other two I mentioned correct? ln(1+x)-ln(1-x) is a homeomorphism and the not? What about $coth(1–x^2)$? It doesn't look onto to me, just like the $x^2/(1-x^2)$...

Comment: Yes, the second function is a homeomorphism $(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, and the last function is not a homeomorphism $(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ because it is not injective (one-to-one) on $(-1,1)$. (Note: you could restrict its domain to a set where it *is* injective and get a homeomorphism, say, from $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$.)

Comment: $tan(\pi x/2)$ would be a homemorphism $(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but then the coth I noted above would have to have its domain restricted as well?

Comment: I don't see $\coth$ above... the first function is $2 \sinh(x)$...

Comment: Sorry I edited into my comment: $coth(1-x^2)$

Comment: None of those functions is $\coth(1-x^2)$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$, then certainly even maps are a no-no, because they violate injectivity.

That said, an homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ need not have some special kind of symmetry (so it need not 'look odd'). Any continuous, strictly monotonic map on $(-1,1)$ which blows up near each endpoint defines an homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There's nothing stopping it from having jump disconuities.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $(X_1,T_1)$ is homeomorphic to $(X_2,T_2)$ and $(X_2,T_2)$ is homeomorphic to $(X_3,T_3)$ then $(X_1,T_1)$ is homeomorphic to $(X_3,T_3).$

The interval $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1).$ E.g. let $g(x)=2x-1.$  A geometric  way to get a homeomorphism from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ is to  homeomorphically "bend" $(-1,1)$ to the semi-circle $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: |x|<1\land y<1\land x^2+(y-1)^2=1\}....$

... And  now map $C$ to $\mathbb R$ by (i). $f((0,0))=0.$ (ii). For $(0,0)\ne p\in C,$ let the line thru $p$ and $(1,0)$ (which is the center of $C$) meet the real axis  at $(f(p),0).$ Then $f:C\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism.

The most common textbook example of a homeomorphism from $(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ is probably $f(x)=\tan (\pi x/2)$.

In general   $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is continuous, strictly monotonic, and $\infty =\lim_{|x|\to 1}|f(x)|$ .