# Homeomorphism $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I saw this other post on homeomorphism, [Homeomorphism $f : (–1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050328/homeomorphism-f-1-1-rightarrow-mathbbr), and I too am learning topology so I thought I'd do another exercise and ask for feedback.

Below are three functions that are homeomorphic from $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}$ with $x \in (0,1)$
$f(x)=\ln \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ with $x \in (0,1)$
$f(x)=\ln \left(x\right)+\frac{x}{1-x}$ with $x \in (0,1)$

All 3 approach (blow up) towards both 0 and 1.

Are my examples correct?

Revised: Added in the domain

Comment: The third one function is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: functions aren't homeomorphic; spaces are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x-1}$

1. Is continuous (rational) whith non null denominator in $(0,1).$
2. Satisfies $f'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}<0$ in $(0,1)$ i.e. is strictly decreasing so, is injective.
3. Also $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$ and  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=-\infty$ so, is surjective.
4. $\;f^{-1}$ is continuous ($f$ continuous and strictly monotone).

As a consequence, $f$ is an homeomorphism. Try the second one.

Comment: The third function is continuous (rational) with non null denominator, it satisfied f'(x)>0 in (0,1), so it is strictly increasing, and the limits go towards negative\positive infinity, so why wouldn't it be injective and surjective?

Comment: You are right. My error: I considered $\log x+x/(x-1)$ instead of $\log x+x/(1-x)$.